# How to pass a file containing queries to youtube-dl?

Tags: bash, python, youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl "ytsearchall:" -x --audio-format "mp3" --min-views 20000 -i --audio-quality 1 --no-playlist --skip-unavailable-fragments --match-filter 'duration < 900'
```

I want for the ytsearchall parameter be a file containing search queries.
this is the python code I am trying.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

f = open('b.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    youtube-dl "ytsearchall:line" -x --audio-format "mp3" --min-views 20000 -i --audio-quality 1 --no-playlist --skip-unavailable-fragments --match-filter 'duration < 900'
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about python, but you could use [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for that (`sudo apt install parallel`; I omit most of your options to increase clarity here):

```bsh
parallel youtube-dl "ytsearchall:{}" -ix :::: /path/to/b.txt
```

By default `parallel` runs as many jobs in parallel as you have CPU cores, which is normally a good choice. If you want to set the number of `youtube-dl` processes run in parallel you can use the `-j` option, e.g. `-j2` for two processes.

Alternatively you could use a `while` loop:

```bsh
while IFS='' read -r l || [ -n "$l" ]; do youtube-dl "ytsearchall:$l" -ix; done </path/to/b.txt
```

Both ways can cope with the last line of your file not ending in a linebreak – `parallel` by design, the loop with the help of the test command `[`.

Comment: What goes between the brackets "ytsearchall:{?}" Are the queries from file automatically inserted?

Comment: @YaredhYare `{}` marks the point where `parallel` fills in each line from the input file. You don't have to change anything except adding your other options after `-ix` and adjusting the path to the text file.